# Can't select specific column of a self referenced table in the index action of the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, activerecord

I am working on a Ruby on Rails API application and I want to select just a few columns of a self-referenced table in the controller's index action.

```
def index
  render json: MenuItem.select('id, english, parent_id')
end
```

But when going to the route I am getting an error:

> ::MissingAttributeError in MenuItemsController#index
>
> missing attribute: persian

My model looks like this:

```
class MenuItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sub_items, class_name: 'MenuItem'
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'MenuItem', optional: true
end
```

And my migration file looks like this:

```
class CreateMenuItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :menu_items do |t|
      t.string :english
      t.string :persian
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_reference :menu_items, :parent, index: true
  end
end
```

I searched the whole day for a solution but didn't file any helpful links.
When I execute `MenuItem.select('id, english, parent_id')` in the rail console I can successfully get the result. But when I try to get data from the controller I am getting that error.

--- Edit: Add some screenshots

### Database

[image: Database]

### Error

[image: Error]

### Seeds

[image: Seed]

### rails console

[image: Console]

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, the problem must be coming from something else you're doing.  That error comes because some code somewhere is trying to use that attribute, maybe you had been using a view and your server hasn't auto-updated since the code change?  Otherwise show us more of the stack trace of the error.

Comment: @smathy I added some screenshots that might be helpful to identify the problem.

Comment: agreed with @smathy, seems like its attribute being used by helper/view or whatever. can you also show us view code and layout, where those menu items being used. Can you also add in your controller `MenuItem.select('id, persian, english, parent_id')` just to ensure that it will work this way?

Comment: It doesn't have any view. It is just an API application.

Comment: Just because it's API doesn't necessarily mean there's no view, eg. jbuilder templates.

Comment: ...but actually, with that `render` it can't be using any template.  Can you click on the "Full Trace" and show that too please.

Comment: Any benefit to adding `.as_json` after the select? You might be inadvertently working with the whole method interface inside the `JSON:` call

Comment: Can we see the whole controller, you could have a before action or an after_action or something that is changing things.